# Vue renders table's whole rows under just first column's header instead of spreading the cells under all columns' headers

Tags: vue.js, html-table

I'm trying to render with Vue a dynamic table with a fixed header. Rows are rendered with `v-for` with a row component and then each row's cells are rendered with `v-for` using some cell components (number of cells is equal to number of `<th>` elements in `<thead>`). The problem is that Vue seems to render the whole rows inside just the first column instead of each cell under the relevant column header.

My code:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
      </tr>          
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr-component v-for="row in dataRows" :key="row.ID">
        <td-component v-for="cell in dataCells" :key="cell.ID"></td-component>
      </tr-component>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Result:

```
        Column 1         | Column 2 | Column 3
Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 |
```

What am I doing wrong? It's not a formatting issue - changing cells widths changes width of Column 1.

PS. `<td>` components have some other elements in them (divs etc.), but always wrapped in `<td>`.

Comment: My guess would be it's a problem in the template of `tr-component`. Could you post that?

Comment: Here you are: it looks something like this `<template>
  <tr class="record">
    <component
      v-for="cell in dataCells" // dataCells is a prop passed from parent, array containing config data for cells
      :key="recordItem.userIndex"
      :is="recordItem.compName"
    ></component>
  </tr>
</template>`

Comment: I have found a culprit - the behaviour was caused by CSS class attached to the <tr-component> with "display: flex". Thank you for trying to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour was caused by CSS class attached to the  with "display: flex".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<template v-for="row in dataRows">
    <tr-component :key="row.ID">
        <td-component v-for="cell in dataCells" :key="cell.ID"></td-component>
    </tr-component>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried to do that. It doesn't seem to work. Additionally I now have a problem that I can't pass the `row` variable as prop value into the <td-component>. Is there a reason why you put `:key="row.ID"` into <tr-component> not template? it's a typo right?

Comment: I'd have to actually play around with it to see. If the key is causing a problem in `tr` then try switching it to the `template`.

Comment: Yes, I did that. If I put it in `<tr>` I get the "Property or method "row" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". But even if I put it in `<template>` with `v-for` not only the rows are still rendered inside cell 1, but also only the first row (out of 4 elements in dataRows is rendered). My code renders all 4 rows.

Comment: I have found a culprit - the behaviour was caused by CSS class attached to the <tr-component> with "display: flex". Thank you for trying to answer my question.